# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input for JSON data processing received form Django backend

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have used Django to develop a web app.

I want to send sting data(msg) in JSON format to frontend, then process the JSON data sent from backend to string, then compare this string in if condition in javascript.

view.py:

```
    @csrf_exempt
def content_checklist_name_url(request):
    msg = "Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists."
    json_data = {'msg': msg}
    return JsonResponse(json_data)
```

Javascript:

```
                       $.ajax({     
        url: '/content_checklist_name_url/',  
        type: 'POST',           
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),           
        cache: false,       
        success: function (data) {        
       
    
            var comment_html = "<div id='myform1'>" + data['log_info'] + "</div>";
            $('#myform1').remove();
            $('#ajax_data').prepend(comment_html);
            $('#myform_input').val('');
        },

    });


            const response = await fetch({% url 'bms:content_checklist_name_url' %});   

            var msg_json = jQuery.parseJSON(response.msg);
```

...

When I tried to receive and process the JSON data sent from backend, error occurs:     Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()

when I debug I found that the POST this URL was sent twice, and in the 2rd time, the msg is none.
So maybe the none value of JSON caused this error, but why it sent twice POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is here  in the "{{json_data}}"

var msg_json = jQuery.parseJSON("{{json_data}}");

you should do something like this

var msg_json = jQuery.parseJSON(response.msg);

Comment: tried your solution, still the same error

Comment: i think that there is a syntax error with your json  , check what your server is returning